# I have the next error when i want to run the android emulator

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oay1H.png)
No matter what device i'm using always i have the same problem, please help me i am a rookie about react-native

i uninstalled and install again the android studio, i expect that you help me. Thanks